# how to javafx hide background header of a tableview?

Tags: tableview, javafx

I'm trying to develop auto complete text, which shows a dropdown of suggestions in tableview popup, and I'm having an issue of how can I hide the whole header-column of tableview in javafx 2.1

Answer (score 14):

Apply a custom stylesheet to the table:

```
table.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("hidden-tableview-headers.css").toExternalForm());
```

Where the file `hidden-tableview-headers.css` is placed in the same location as the class loading the css resource and contains the line:

```
.column-header-background { visibility: hidden; -fx-padding: -1em; }
```

The `visibility: hidden` attribute tells JavaFX not to draw the node, but still leave space where the heading was.  As the header is 1 row of text height high, you can tell the invisible header not to take up any space by setting `-fx-padding: -1em;`.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea, but this will keep an empty space instead of the column header, and I want to remove it.

Comment: Added a -fx-padding setting to the suggested css so that the invible column header does not take up any space on the screen (as recommended by an anonymous stackoverflow user).

Comment: @jewelsea, I suggest to use `-fx-padding: -2em;` instead of `-1em` as one was still leaving some space when I tried.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is very simple; after the tableview renders, we can get the table header and make invisible, therefor the table header doesn't have to re-layout when the table view layout changes.
To catch table rendering is done, we can use width property change, and hide the table header

Here is the code:

```
tableView.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
            // Get the table header
            Pane header = (Pane)tableView.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
            if(header!=null && header.isVisible()) {
              header.setMaxHeight(0);
              header.setMinHeight(0);
              header.setPrefHeight(0);
              header.setVisible(false);
              header.setManaged(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add additional .css file you may use your existing css:

```
.hide-header .column-header-background { 
    visibility: hidden; -fx-padding: -1em;
}
```

Where `.hide-header` is random name which you should add to your java code:

```
table.getStyleClass().add("hide-header");
```