# How to hide header of TreeTableView?

Tags: java, header, javafx, treetableview

Is there any way to hide the header of a [TreeTableView](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html) in JavaFX?

I am asking, because I have treestructured data which I always want to present within three columns, whereas two of them always will have the same size. So there is no need for the user to modify any columnspecific properties. Also there wont be the possiblity of filtering, sorting the data, since it is just not necessary.

So I am wondering if it is possible to hide the header of the TreeTableView, because it just costs space. Within the [documentation](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/TreeTableView+User+Experience+Documentation) as well as in the sources, I couldnt find any hints to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course jewelsea already answered that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324464/how-to-javafx-hide-background-header-of-a-tableview?rq=1). Just the topic of the question was little misleading, but it works the same way for TreeTableView.